# Unable to inject Automapper and other layers using structuremap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, structuremap, structuremap4

I am implementing `AutoMapper` and `structureMap` in my `WebAPI` solution. I am unable to inject automapper using structuremap .I also want to inject my DAL,BAL and API layers. How do I do that with structure Map. I googled and thought I found a solution but that seems incompatible with the latest version of structure map. DefaultRegistry class doesnt compile.  It doesnt find keywords MapperConfiguration, IMapperConfiguration, IMapper Please see my code below

AutoMapper

```
public class DomainToDtoMapping : Profile
{
    public DomainToDtoMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<BaseEntity, BaseDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Movie, MoviesDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

**DefaultRegistry class in Webapi project**

```
public class DefaultRegistry : Registry {
    #region Constructors and Destructors
    public DefaultRegistry() {
        var profiles = from t in typeof(DefaultRegistry).Assembly.GetTypes()
                       where typeof(Profiles).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                       select (Profiles) Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        //For each Profile, include that profile in the MapperConfiguration
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            foreach (var profile in profiles)
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(profile);
            }
        });

        //Create a mapper that will be used by the DI container
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        //Register the DI interfaces with their implementation
        For<IMapperConfiguration>().Use(config);
        For<IMapper>().Use(mapper);

        //Register the UserRepository and pass instance of Mapper to its constructor
        For<IMovieBusiness>().Use<MovieBusiness>()
            .Ctor<IMapper>().Is(mapper);

        For<IConnectionFactory>().Use<ConnectionFactory>();
        For<IMovieRepository>().Use<MovieRepository>();
        For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<UnitOfWork>();
        For<IMovieService>().Use<MovieService>();
        For<IMovieBusiness>().Use<MovieBusiness>();
    }
```

**DataAccess Layer**

```
public class MovieRepository : GenericRepository<Movie>, IMovieRepository
{
    IConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;

    public MovieRepository(IConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }
}

public class MovieService : IMovieService
{
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public MovieService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

**Business Access Layer**

```
public class MovieBusiness: IMovieBusiness
{
    IMovieService _movieService;

    public MovieBusiness(IMovieService movieService)
    {
        _movieService = movieService;
    }
}
```

**WebAPI**

```
public class MoviesController : ApiController
{
    IMovieBusiness _movieBusiness;
    public MoviesController(IMovieBusiness movieBusiness)
    {
        _movieBusiness = movieBusiness;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable to inject"? What behavior are you seeing? Is there an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: As  I have mentioned in my post the DefaultRefgistry class isnt compiling. I tried to follow this  example https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/using-automapper-with-structuremap-in-asp-net-web-api/      but my current version of structuremap doesnt seem to recognise a lot of keywords.This is mentioned in my post as well